# golang illegal base64 data at input byte

Tags: python, go, base64, decode

Python

```
>>> print(base64.b64decode('//Py+vX7suTx8A=='))
b'\xff\xf3\xf2\xfa\xf5\xfb\xb2\xe4\xf1\xf0'
```

Go

```
>>> data, err := base64.RawStdEncoding.DecodeString("//Py+vX7suTx8A==")
err -> illegal base64 data at input byte 14
```

Why can Python decode this string while Go fails?

Comment: It has padding, so isn’t RawStdEncoding. Use StdEncoding

Answer (score 2):

`RawStdEncoding`, as its name suggests, accepts "raw" base64 encoded strings. The string you used on the other hand is padded with 2 "="s. try removing them and you should get no errors:

```golang
data, err := base64.RawStdEncoding.DecodeString("//Py+vX7suTx8A") // no paddings
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("err: %v\n", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("data: %v\n", data)
```

And as [@JimB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32880/jimb) said, if you want to decode padded strings anyway, just use `base64.StdEncoding` with the padded version.

```golang
data, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("//Py+vX7suTx8A==")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("err: %v\n", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("data: %v\n", data)
```